# Why does vim replace with confirmation only replace the first occurrence in the each line?

Tags: substitute

For example, for a line

> X X X

with the command

> :s/X/Y/c

vim will only replace the first occurrence, namely the first 'X' to 'Y', is there a way to let vim go through all the 'X' and replace it while asking for confirmation for each replacement?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: thx, I just referred to http://vimregex.com/ and only interpret the meaning of 'c' literally as 'Confirm Each substitution', now I know what does 'Each' really mean :)

Answer (score 11):

By default Vim replaces only first occurrence. You should add `g` to you substitution: `:s/X/Y/cg`.

Vim will then let you change each X one by one (confirming with `y`) or all at once (confirming with `a`).

Answer (score 0):

I cannot add comment to previous answer, so I decided to post my own.

As it's already been mentioned, you should use 'g' flag to replace all occurrences. But for `:s/X/Y/cg` it will still replace only in current line. Reference from `:help :s`

```
4.2 Substitute                      *:substitute*
                            *:s* *:su*
:[range]s[ubstitute]/{pattern}/{string}/[flags] [count]

            ......
    
            When [range] and [count] are omitted, replace in the
            current line only.

            ......
```

You can specify range after colon symbol, like `%` (`:%s/X/Y/cg`), to replace in the whole file. Or you can specify range from current line to document's end by `.,$` (`:.,$s/X/Y/cg`). More about ranges you can see in `:help :range`: